# Not able to store and retrieve data from one step to another - in Spring BatchJob

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

We are working on a Spring Batch Job, where we need to store data computed in one step and retrieve it in the next step.

I am able to achieve this in a standalone manner using the below implementation in spring batch source

http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps

But we are implementing it in a CLIENT/MASTER and SERVER way. Where the CLIENT/MASTER is having code related to Job and partitioning.

Client is out side the EAR and is used by Shell script to call the Batch Job.

Bean config on Client side:

```
<job id="esk956" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="importSalesAlert-master">
        <partition handler="partitionHandler" partitioner="partitioner" />
    </step>

</job>

<bean id="partitioner"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.SimplePartitioner" />
```

All the code related to Steps and its implementations(Readers, Processors and
 Writers) are on SERVER/SLAVE side.

SLAVE CoDE:

```
<step id="importSalesAlert" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <chunk reader="salesAlertFileItemReader" processor="nucleusItemProcessor"
            writer="nucleusItemWriter" commit-interval="10" />
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="loggingStepListener" />
        </listeners>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

We are using a JMS integration and Weblogic as the webserver.

Please guide us in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pass information from a partitioner to the executioner (steps) you can set it in the stepExecutionContext at partition time and then use late-binding to set the values.  have a look at the example here (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionJdbcJob.xml) and look particularly at the value `${stepExecutionContext[minValue]}` in the itemReader.  this value is from the stepExecutionContext set by the partitioner.

you can also access other late-binding variables just as jobExecutionContext and jobParameters  in the same way.  just ensure your itemreader has the attribute `scope="step"` in it's root element and that you either use the namespace to declare your jobRepository `<batch:job-repository.../>` or declare the `<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />` bean (but don't have both).  see here (http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#step-scope) for more info.

Comment: Thank you and we are able to pass the values by overriding the partitioner for the Job and passing the required values from the Client side to Slave side code where steps are defined.